# A new kind of fractal?

Tags: complex-numbers, fractals

http://www.gibney.de/does_anybody_know_this_fractal

Is this some known kind of fractal?

Update: This one got a lot of great feedback from around the net. I summarized it in the section labeled "Update 24.10.2012".

Comment: In case anyone is wondering about the number of upvotes, this is linked from [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4659840).

Comment: What are the limits of your plot? For example, what is the complex number in the upper right corner of the plot? Is it 4000 + 4000i?

Comment: Chris: My original question contained a link to the page where I describe this thing and give more informations. For some reason this question got edited heavily and the link got dropped. Here it is: http://www.gibney.de/does_anybody_know_this_fractal

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer, but I didn't remove the link - it's still there. I've now edited to include the limits of the plot as well (FYI, we prefer questions to be as complete as possible - links to external sites often go dead, especially on a timescale of years).

Comment: Your image appears to be the [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion) w.r.t. the origin of [a regularly repeating pattern](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5QEkG.png); the latter reminds me of [a higher-dimensional variation](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67589/856) of [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

Comment: If this is another Batman curve, someone needs to notify ShreevastaR... :-)

Comment: Chris: I see it now. Wow. I never saw a website that edits user content in such a drastic way. You even write in my name sentences like "i blogged about it". You copy images you dont own. Without asking. Thats probably illegal. And you neither ask nor inform the author of all that. And to make things complete you put a "nofollow" attribute into the link to the source. And you offer no way to delete all that. If you would have asked before the edit - no problem. But this way it is just wrong. I reverted it. Please leave it now as it is or delete the whole question. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that somewhat of an overreaction of someone who's been on this website for two days and isn't aware of norms? Furthermore, I don't see any "nofollow" attributes in the source of the edits, if they were added that was an automatic addition.

Comment: The second link in the OP post is dead.

Comment: Jam: Because I integrated that part into the post which the first link points to. I removed the second link from the question now.

Answer (score 8):

Probably a part of what we see is due to rounding in your program: note that the value at $c$ is the same as that at $ic$ so that the image should be symmetric under rotation by 90 degrees. This roughly is the case, apart from the deformed squares all over the place. In fact, they all occupy one quadrant like region with one vertex at a point with a high value, probably due to rounding. 
Without the squares you would have a better approximation to the real picture.

Comment: I suspected that for a while, but it looks like there are no rounding errors involved. See this update: http://www.gibney.de/does_anybody_know_this_fractal_-_part_2

Answer (score 2):

The intensity as defined is $0$ for almost all values of $z$, so it is unclear how the visualization relates to the definition.  If you post the code that generated the images you will have a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer, and that would also address @doetoe's observation of what are apparently artifacts.

Comment: You are right. The check if the result of a division is a gaussian integer is actually checking if the result is near a gaussian integer. Thats why the intensity is higher then 0 for most values.